# Google Sheets is not compatible with GA4, only with Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

When trying to add a new report in Google Sheets for one of my websites in order to collect data for a dashboard, I've noticed that only UA properties are visible in the list - **not** GA4 properties. How can this be? Is Google Sheets not compatible with GA4, and if that's the case, will it be in the future?

It's not possible to downgrade from GA4 to UA either, so I don't know what to do here.

Comment: What exactly does google sheets have to do with Google analytics are you using an add on or something?

Comment: You can find answer in this duplicate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70711082/google-analytics-v4-addon-for-google-sheets/75414215#75414215

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using this [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)

It was designed to work with Universal analyitcs. I am not sure if it working with the reporting api or if its even older and using the core reporting api.

Either way it is not going to work with Ga4 accounts.  The apis for Ga4 are still in beta and not everything has been updated yet.

You can not downgrade a GA4 account to UA and you cant create a new UA account.

I will check with the team if they plan on updating this addon.

Comment: You're assuming correctly - I'm using the Spreadsheet Add-on. And thank you so much for checking with the team. Appreciate it.